# when editing 1 branch in git other get updated to

Tags: git

I have just started using Git and I am facing a problem relating to branches and how they work.

I have 2 branches in my repo, my I am on b1 and I make some changes in the code using sublime text, the same changes are reflected in b2.

Why do I see b1 changes in b2?

Comment: How do you confirm that the changes are reflected in other branch? can you explain the exact steps you are performing and git commands you are running to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

That typically happen when you have untracked files: they are not modified/deleted when switching branches.

So modifying a file in branch1, and switching to branch2 would mean seeing the same file, with its recent modification "in branch2".

You need to add and commit it in the right branch.
Then, when you switch to the other branch, you won't see any modification done in the first branch.

Comment: Yeah that was happening